# Why add a new operator and use lift rather than just using map in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, reactivex

I'm new to ReactiveX and trying to understand the `lift` operator. What I understand so far is that it's useful in allowing custom operators to be used in a reactive chains but also introduces overhead and can prevent operator fusion. I'm not quite getting how a custom operator and `lift` is different than just using `map`. For example, in the [ReactiveX docs for "Implementing Your Own Operators"](https://reactivex.io/documentation/implement-operator.html), the below code is given

```java
Observable foo = barObservable.ofType(Integer).map({it*2}).lift(new myOperator<T>()).map({"transformed by myOperator: " + it});
```

```java
public class myOperator<T> implements Operator<T> {
  public myOperator( /* any necessary params here */ ) {
    /* any necessary initialization here */
  }

  @Override
  public Subscriber<? super T> call(final Subscriber<? super T> s) {
    return new Subscriber<t>(s) {
      @Override
      public void onCompleted() {
        /* add your own onCompleted behavior here, or just pass the completed notification through: */
        if(!s.isUnsubscribed()) {
          s.onCompleted();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable t) {
        /* add your own onError behavior here, or just pass the error notification through: */
        if(!s.isUnsubscribed()) {
          s.onError(t);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(T item) {
        /* this example performs some sort of simple transformation on each incoming item and then passes it along */
        if(!s.isUnsubscribed()) {
          transformedItem = myOperatorTransformOperation(item);
          s.onNext(transformedItem);
        }
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Is this not equivalent to

```java
Observable foo = barObservable.ofType(Integer).map({it*2}).map(myOperatorTransformOperation).map({"transformed by myOperator: " + it});
```

?

Comment: It is a matter of taste and code organization. Also using `lift`, you can't really stop the subscription chain from progressing beyond your operator because you have to return some observer that will be subscribed up the chain unconditionally. With `extends Observable`, you don't have to.

Comment: The docs gives a simple and understandable example of using a lifted operator. Of course  there is no reason to reimplement existing operators via lift but we had to give some starting point for devs. Most real-world custom operators are so complicated to look at as a beginner people would just insta tune-out.

Comment: Thanks @akarnokd! I agree that having something too complex in the docs would turn people away. I do think though that the docs should at least state what the benefit of that custom operator is over using the transform function in a map operation. Or, if there is no benefit and it's purely a contrived example for demonstration purposes, the docs should say that

Comment: Docs usually have a mix of idiomatic snippets ("here is how we intend you to use this API and where it makes sense") and contrived examples ("this is a basic example of what this API does but should never appear in actual project"). This sounds like the latter but without any clarification and without my having any prior experience with ReactiveX, that's hard to tell

Comment: I have no control over that website and no means to fix it either.